# What is the most efficient way of seeing whether any of five strings are identical?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-comparison

Assume that we have a list of 5 strings:

```
list = ['hello', 'alloha', 'hi there', 'good day', 'hello']
```

I want to see whether any of the strings are identical (bonus: and if any strings are identical get the index of the identical elements in the list).

What is the most efficient way to solve that small task? Will it work for bigger list with more than two identical elements?

I was thinking of perhaps (somehow) comparing the lengths of each string to each other and then if lengths math compare letters on the same position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash them with a set and compare the lengths

```
if len(set(mylist)) != len(mylist):
    print("some members match!")
else:
    print("no members match")
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to get an idea of if they exist *while also* getting the indices is to create a little function that holds this information in the return value.

Specifically, it checks for membership using a set and, if similar indices are found returns a list of these (ergo, similar words exist) while, if none are found, returns an empty list (meaning, no matches):

```
def sim(ls):
    s = set()
    for i, j in enumerate(ls):
        if j not in s:
            s.add(j)  # add the value
        else:
            yield i   # yield the index
```

You can then grab the results yielded from this function and check against the value in an `if` condition if so required:

```
lst = ['hello', 'alloha', 'hi there', 'good day', 'hello']
res = list(sim(lst))   # get indices if they exist

# check against them
if res:
    print("Similar values in indices :", res)
else:
    print("print("No similar words")
```

This prints out:

```
Similar values in indices : [4]
```